# Is it possible to mix content in Drupal 6's Views Slideshow module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using Views Slideshow in Drupal 6 and I am using it to show a slideshow of Case Studies. Each Case Study has a number of images which work fine at the moment, but I want to integrate a YouTube video somewhere in the same slideshow. I have managed to integrate it in the same View using the Embedded Media Field module for YouTube, but it sits outside of the slideshow.

I have even experienced the behavior where the video keeps fading in and out as the image slides move?!

Currently I am adding both as separate content fields and selecting 'hide if empty' on the YouTube content.

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Use http://drupal.org/project/uicarousel or http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel

Comment: For demo see http://d2010.thecgf.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS tricks to reposition it properly.

Better yet, If you are using Drupal 7, you can even use the Field Group module to wrap more than one fields inside a DIV or a SPAN so that the group can be treated as a single entity ... much like a single items in a list. That should keep your video and inside the same container as the image of the slide.

I believe that a similar module exists for Drupal 6, but I am not sure.